# update/assign a user an empID in Users table

Tags: sql

I want to update/assign a user an empID in Users table. My Update below update all rows/users with the empID and not just the selected user(cbArea.Text).

```
string update = "Update Users set First= '" + this.txtFirst.Text + "', empID =(SELECT DISTINCT ID from Employer where area= '" + this.cbArea.Text + "') WHERE First= '" + this.txtFirst.Text + "'" ;
```

Comment: Why are you SETing First when First is in the WHERE clause with the same value? That isn't doing anything.

Comment: And that's the answer..Works when I took that out. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First= '" + this.txtFirst.Text already in WHERE clause. When removed from set it works fine.